# How to minimise this sql query

Tags: sql, optimization

```
SELECT sale1, 
       sale2 , 
       sale3 
FROM   ( 
              SELECT Sum(todayssale) AS sale1 
              FROM   sale_details USE index (index_sale) 
              WHERE  productid='242431' 
              AND    exacttime >= '2015-06-29 14:29:36' ) a 
JOIN 
       ( 
              SELECT sum(todayssale) AS sale2 
              FROM   sale_details USE index (index_sale) 
              WHERE  productid='242431' 
              AND    exacttime >= '2015-06-23 14:29:36' ) b 
JOIN 
       ( 
              SELECT sum(todayssale) AS sale3 
              FROM   sale_details USE index (index_sale) 
              WHERE  productid='242431' 
              AND    date>='2015-06-29' ) c
```

I want to minimise the query execution time. It takes too long to retrieve the data.

Comment: which rdbms are you using?

Answer (score 2):

you can use `CASE` like this and remove the use of `joins`.

```
SELECT
    sum(CASE WHEN exacttime >= '2015-06-29 14:29:36' THEN todayssale ELSE 0 END) as sale1
    sum(CASE WHEN exacttime >= '2015-06-23 14:29:36' THEN todayssale ELSE 0 END) as sale2
    sum(CASE WHEN date>='2015-06-29' THEN todayssale ELSE 0 END) as sale3
FROM   sale_details USE index (index_sale) 
WHERE  productid='242431' 
AND (exacttime >= '2015-06-23 14:29:36' OR date>='2015-06-29')
```

Comment: Removes the joins, and more importantly also removes the subqueries. +1.

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT Sum(todayssale) FROM sale_details WHERE productid='242431' AND exacttime >= '2015-06-29 14:29:36') as sale1, 
    (SELECT Sum(todayssale) FROM sale_details WHERE productid='242431' AND exacttime >= '2015-06-23 14:29:36') as sale2 , 
    (SELECT Sum(todayssale) FROM sale_details WHERE productid='242431' AND date >= '2015-06-29') as sale3
```